# How to add a label below polar histogram

Tags: matlab, label

I would like to add a text below polar histogram text.

Originally, I have a regular histogram and I can use **xlabel** to put a text as follows:

```
histogram_orientation_of_blobs = histogram(orientation, 'Normalization','probability');
xlabel(['orientation ($^{\circ}$)'],'Interpreter','latex','fontsize', 12)
```

However, if I use

```
histogram_orientation_of_blobs = polarhistogram(orientation, 'Normalization','probability');
xlabel(['orientation ($^{\circ}$)'],'Interpreter','latex','fontsize', 12)
```

I cannot get it. I guess it is because there is not xlabel on a polar histogram, but how do I add a description for this plot below the polar histogram?

Answer (score 2):

Hacky semi-manual solution:

```
theta = 0:0.01:2*pi;
rho = sin(2*theta).*cos(2*theta);
polarplot(theta,rho)
ax = gca;
ax.ThetaAxis.Label.String = 'foo';
ax.ThetaAxis.Label.Rotation = 0;
ax.ThetaAxis.Label.Units = 'normalized';
ax.ThetaAxis.Label.Position = [0.5,-0.06,0];
```

code output:

[image: Code output]